# 403 forbiden error on submiting form data XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem submitting form data with **XMLHttpRequest().**

The form in question is a basic comment submission form. I have an onsubmit event listener on the form. When the user submits the form, I create an XMLHttpRequest() request, get the form data into a **FormData** object and submit. No matter what I do, I always get a 403 error on the load event listener. The strange thing is this function submits another form (newsletter subscription) and it is processed just fine. I have tried submitting both forms to the same php script server side but only the subscription form data is processed, the comment form data always returns a 403. Even when I submit to different scripts, the result is the same.
I have ruled out file permissions since the file is accessible by the browser on one instance and not the other.
I have even created a new **FormData** object with the data from the form and submitted it but the result is the same.
Strange still the form data submits correctly on my local server. The problem arises when I upload it to online server
Here is my code:

```
function commentSubmissionResponse(event) {
  let response=this.responseText.split(":");
  let error=this.sender.querySelector(".error")
  if (response[0]=='OK') {
    error.innerHTML="Your comment has been successfully submitted. Thank you"
    this.sender.querySelector('*[type=submit]').disabled=true
  }else if(response[0]=='BAD'){
    error.innerHTML=response[1]
  }
  else{
    error.innerHTML="Submiting your comment failed!, please try again later"
  }
}
 //This function was handling submission of another form to the same target but only worked for the other form, so I have split them up, changed the server side target, recombined them, everything I can think of. This is my latest version

function comments(event){
  let xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhttp.open("POST","/serversideReceiver.php",true);
  //let formData=new FormData(form); here I was just submitting the form data directly but after no I success tried to extract the data
  const form=document.forms['comment']

  let formData=new FormData(form)
  xhttp.sender=form;
  formData.set("comment",true);
  formData.set("name",form.elements['name'].value)
  formData.set("email",form.elements['email'].value)
  formData.set("subject",form.elements['subject'].value)
  formData.set("message",form.elements['message'].value)

  xhttp.onload=commentSubmissionResponse
  xhttp.send(formData)
  return false
}
```

The php code:

```
//This is accessed by both xmlhttprequests (since they are now split),
// but even when they are joined, it only works for the **newsletter** data.

<?php 
include_once 'DBConnector.php';

if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])){
        $name=sanityCheck($_POST['name']);
        $email=sanityCheck($_POST['email']);

        $test_email_stmt=$connection->prepare("SELECT * from subscribers where subscriber_email = ?");
        $test_email_stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
        $test_email_stmt->execute();


        $result = $test_email_stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if($row){
            echo("BAD:".$row['subscriber_email']." already registered!");
            $test_email_stmt->close();
            return;
        }

        $test_email_stmt->close();
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers (subscriber_name,subscriber_email) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->affected_rows){
            echo "OK";
        }else{
            echo "Error: Registration Failed. Try again later";
        }
        $stmt->close();

    }elseif (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
        $name=sanityCheck($_POST['name']);
        $email=sanityCheck($_POST['email']);
        $subject=sanityCheck($_POST['subject']);
        $message=sanityCheck($_POST['message']);

        $stmt=$connection->prepare("INSERT into comments (commenter_name,commenter_email,commenter_subject,commenter_message) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$name,$email,$subject,$message);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->affected_rows){
            echo "OK";
        }else{
            echo "Error: Comment Submission Failed. Please try again later";
        }
        $stmt->close();

    }else{
   
        die();
    }
}else{
   
        die();
    }
```

I have tried in chrome, firefox, and mobile browsers and they all succeed in submitting **newsletter** form data but not **comment** form data.
Can somebody please point me to the right direction, thanks

Comment: This error is coming from the webserver, not the PHP script. You need to check its configuration to see why it doesn't allow the request.

Comment: true, when I turn off mod security, it works and then reverts when I turn it off. I have googled for rules to turn it off for this file, but no rule works. `SetEnvIf Request_URI /commentTarget.php$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off ` .I have contacted my host provider or may be any one has ideas on how to do it?

Comment: You could check the access logs to see which modsec rule was actually tripped. Another option is to send the same request to https://coreruleset.org/serversideReceiver.php or whatever to see if it trips. Also you are requesting serversideReceiver but the env you gave above is for commentTarget. Do you have a sample payload that you're posting? Does removing some of the parameters in the POST request help?